# How do I use JSON sent from a POST Request to C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

So as the title says, I'm looking to manipulate JSON received from a client side AJAX POST request in a C# backend.  Here is my code:

**Client side:**

```
var myData = { Name: "tyler", Age: 3 };
var moreData = {
    documentName: "Doc-109",
    attachments: {
        name: "Attachment 11"
    }
};
$.post('/NMISProduct/Index', { myData: myData, moreData: moreData }, function(returnedData) {
    console.log(returnedData);
}, 'json');
```

**C# backend:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string myData, string moreData)
{
    //I want to return myData.Name + moreData.attachments.name in JSON format - How do I do this?
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: what do u see in the console?

Comment: Why not just make a type, and then the type contains properties of those types? Seems like it would make more sense and be easier, unless I am misunderstanding the purpose.

Comment: Create a C# class say `MyClass` with - `DataName` and `AttachmentsName`. Then create a new Instance of class `var cls = new MyClass()` and assign those properties with the data you got in `POST`. then use `return Json(cls, JsonBehavior.AllowGet)` in your controller action to send data back to AJAX call.

Comment: You need to serialize to two strings you sent as json, or else it is just a string and does not contain properties. I would create to partial classes, that represent the two json objects you are sending to the controller, so in the method you can serialize(desalinize) them accordingly.

Comment: Your submitting objects (as name/value pairs), not strings. Create classes on the server to represent the data your posting

Comment: Do I have to create a class every time I want to receive an object?  Or is there another way?  Also, how do I create nested name value pairs like in the case of `moreData.attachments.name`?  

`public class MoreData { 
    attachments {get; set;} 
}`?

Comment: You can always just have a lot of parameter names e.g. `string Name, int Age, ...` but that will soon get out of control. For the object you have shown you need 3 classes - `public class Attachment { public string name { get; set; }`, `public class moreData { public string documentName { get; set; } public Attachment attachments { get; set; }}` and `public class myData { public string Name { get; set; } public int Age { get; set; }}` and then the controller method would be `public ActionResult Index(myData  model1, moreData model2)`.

Comment: Of course you could just have one class containing all properties and just create one javascript object on the client.